# Javascript Dynamic SVG with Marker

Tags: javascript, svg

I have some javascript that is generating SVG paths ontop of some data to show job progression. I have the lines working that show the connection between one box to another, but I am unable to add a marker arrow.

I am referencing my arrow by using the following structure:

```
<svg id="svg1" width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
      <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" 
              markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
              orient="auto">
        <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="context-stroke"/>
      </marker>
    </defs>
    <path id="path1" class="path" marker-end="url(#Triangle)" fill="none" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>
```

The issue is that it is not generating the triangle correctly and almost looks like its a cut-off square? The triangle should be on the bottom right as the path is connecting the top box to the bottom box.

[image]

**JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qLhunt7k/

Any idea as to why it's not looking like the triangle I am expecting?

Comment: The issue is in your CSS: `stroke-width: 0.7em !important;` (in both 'path' & '.path')

Comment: @targumon Even removing that styling on this end, I am only seeing a cut-off object it seems like? It doesn't appear to be drawing the full shape that I can tell.

Comment: Also remove both `fill: none !important;` (and btw, avoid 'important' as much as you can. it's a nuke. using it without a really good reason will only bring you pain) and change `refX` to 10, while making `path1` stop 10 units before its end point.

Comment: Your svg element is not wide enough and **not height enough**. This is the reason why the marker is cut. Also you should remove `stroke-width: 0.7em !important;` from the css. An other problem I see is that the SVG element has a fixed width  while the rest of your HTML is responsive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is due to a number of factors:

1. The marker is off the bottom of your SVG because your line ends at the bottom of your SVG.  The marker's offset (`refX` and `refY`) is at the base of the arrowhead.  So the marker is drawn so that its base (the widest part) is placed where the line ends.  So you can only see the top pixel of it.
2. You can prevent the clipping, and make the marker visible, by setting `overflow: visible` on the SVG.  But you also have to do the same to the `#svgContainer` container div.

   ```
   #svgContainer {
     ...
     overflow: visible;
   }

   #svgContainer svg {
     overflow: visible;
   }
   ```

   An alternative would be to not draw your line all the way to the bottom.  So that you leave space at the bottom for the marker to be drawn.  Eg. change the path generator to something like:

   ```
   " V" + (endY-30));
   ```

   I've used 30 here because it matches a `stroke-width` of `0.7em`.  I would recommend changing your CSS to use a `px` value for the `stroke-width`. Otherwise, a change to the font-size in the future may end up breaking the markers again.

   If you choose this approach, you'll also need allow horizontal room for the marker when you calculate the SVG width. Eg:

   ```
   if (svg.getAttribute("width") < (endX + stroke * 3))
      svg.setAttribute("width", (endX + stroke * 3));
   ```
3. Next, the `path {}` rule is causing issues.  That general definition for `path` is over-riding the `fill="context-stroke"` attribute in your marker definition.  This is causing the marker to have a large stroke, which again is overflowing the marker bounds and making it look like a rectangle.  The fix is to get rid of the `path {}` style.

   ```
   path {
   }
   ```
4. The last remaining issue is the `fill="context-stroke"`.  This is a new SVG2 thing which is not well supported yet. For instance, it works on Chrome, but doesn't seem to work on Firefox yet.  So for now, I recommend just using a plain fill in the marker definition.

   ```
   <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" 
           markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
           orient="auto">
     <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="#000"/>
   </marker>
   ```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ptLc1gyx/

Comment: Wow, I appreciate the detail on this. SVG is new to me but this clears up a lot. I appreciate your time!